# Plotting points using adjacency matrix

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

Given an adjacency matrix on n vertices and a polygon on n vertices, how to add edges from adjacency matrix on the Polygon?

eg: if polygon is {(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)} and the adjacency matrix has 1 in the position corresponding to vertices 1 and 4 then how to draw that line on the polygon.

It would be great if there is a function to execute this.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[5]
pts = RandomReal[1, {6, 2}];
pts = pts[[FindShortestTour[pts][[2]]]];
am = RandomChoice[{.7, .3} -> {0, 1}, {6, 6}];
```

`AdjacencyGraph` using the polygon vertices as vertex coordinates:

```
Labeled[AdjacencyGraph[am, VertexCoordinates -> pts, DirectedEdges -> False, 
                       Vertexlabels->"Name", Prolog -> {Yellow, Polygon[pts]}], 
        MatrixForm[am], Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OP's example:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
am = {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
Labeled[AdjacencyGraph[am, VertexCoordinates -> pts, DirectedEdges -> False, 
                  VertexLabels->"Name", Prolog -> {Opacity[.5, Yellow], Polygon[pts]}], 
        MatrixForm[am], Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Elegant... but it doesn't show the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where the adjacency matrix shows a link from `pt[[1]]` to `pt[[4]]` and from `pt[[2]]` to `pt[[3]]`:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
adMat = {{0, 0, 0, 1},
   {0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 1, 0, 0}};
myfig = Graphics[

  {{Opacity[0.2], Yellow, Polygon[pts]},
   {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts]}, 
   Line@({pts[[#1]], pts[[#2]]} & @@@ Position[adMat, 1])
   }]
```

[image]

This assumes one needs only one entry to link two points (e.g., just `1 -> 2` without `2 -> 1`).